# How to fixed text field position in all iphone device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am need set `UITextField` position fixed in all device screen.

I want to set `UITextField` position fixed.

Please Help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You should atleast show what you have down already.

Comment: yes you are right. but sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1). It will help :

Or refer to any `auto layout` tutorial. There are plenty online.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer

Answer (score 2):

there are three types `layout` using in `iOS`

1. *autolayout*

   [Tutorial1](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/),[Tutorial2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

if you are not interested in `autolayout` , go to second option

2. *autosizing*

   [Tutorial1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html),[Tutorial2](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling).

   [image]

   3. *autoresizingMask*  - here you can set height,width, x and Y coordinates programmatically

   [Tutorial1](http://tinyletter.com/iosdev/letters/ios-dev-tip-35-use-uiview-autoresizingmask),[Tutorial2](http://nachbaur.com/blog/basics-positioning-uiviews)

Comment: i already used auto resizing but its not work for this situation.

Comment: your question is nice and good one , this question hopes for multiple users, auto resizing  -- design the small screens use iPhone 4 , if set one screen it automatically changed all screens , I used auto resizing in more than 12 projects, just once understand the concept , there after you can handle in easy

Comment: i also use autoresize in my all project. i got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **autolayout** to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a `UITextField` into your `UIViewController` inside the `UIStoryboard`. Then you need to set the `constraints` by right clicking from the `UITextField` to the positions you want to fix it to.

Use following constraints:

- Top Space to Container
- Center Horizontally in Container
- Leading Space to Container
- Trailing Space to Container

Here is an example how I did it:

[image]

Like you can see in the screenshot, there are also constraints to the `UILabel` called **Title**, `Center X` and `Vertical Spacing`. If you have other elements above, you have to position the `UITextField` relative to these elements.

**And always think about:**

Insert all elements you want inside your view, then start to fix them with constraints, starting from the first at the top and going down till you prepared all `UIControls` in your `UIView`. And use the preview view inside the `Assistent Editor` ( <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> ), and select at the top `Preview`:

[image]

Here you can insert phones you want and every change on constraints inside the `UIStoryboard` will be displayed here immediately, so you don't have to run your app every time again just to see, something again didn't work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving answer