# iPhone Same UI for All screen resolution without autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to develop an iPhone application which target iOS7 & above . No auto-layout. supported iPhone models are iPhone 4, 4s, 5 ,5s, 6 & 6plus. how can i design my storyboard to support all these models. I have done small POC in which storyboard view-controller's size property set to iPhone 3.5-inch. then i ran into above all devices it looks good. is this correct approach to make an iPhone app . or else i want separate storyboard for iPhone 4 , iPhone 5 and iPhone 6plus.  please suggest me good tutorial or explanation.    I am not familiar with Autolayout . can i design without autolayout?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980223/how-to-fixed-text-field-position-in-all-iphone-device/31980826#31980826

Comment: why you dont want to use autolayout?

Comment: I will suggest `autolayout`.

Comment: would you tell what are the difficulties to face when not using Autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalable UI can be designed without using autolayout (though autolayout is the preferred approach, maybe difficult to understand first but very powerful).

Here is a [tutorial](http://floatlearning.com/2012/11/designing-for-multiple-screens-in-ios/) explaining approach to design scalable UI (in storyboard) without autolayouts

Answer (score -1):

> [Create an iOS app without storyboards in XCode 5](http://www.wastedpotential.com/create-an-ios-app-without-storyboards-in-xcode-5/)

**Another Solution**

There is no option in **XCode6** for directly creating an Empty Application as in **XCode5** and earlier. But still we can create application without **Storyboard** in **XCode6** by following these steps:

*Create an Single View Application with XCode6*
Remove **Main.storyboard** and **LaunchScreen.xib** (select them, right-click, and choose to either remove them from the project, or delete them completely).

Remove "*Main storyboard file base name*" and "*Launch screen interface file base name*" entries in **Info.plist** file.
Open AppDelegate.m, and edit **applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions** so that it looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**For Swift:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```